# get nested json data using datatable

Tags: jquery

i tried but unable find every time some sort of error comes,please help me out,
the json Data:

```
{ "siteList": [ 
    { "siteName": "Site1", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S1device1", "count": "1" }, 
            { "deviceName": "S1device2", "count": "2" } 
            ] 
    }, 
    { "siteName": "Site2", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S2device1", "count": "1" }, 
            { "deviceName": "S2device2", "count": "2" } 
            ] 
    }, 
    { "siteName": "Site3", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S3device1", "count": "1" }, 
            { "deviceName": "S3device2", "count": "2" } 
            ] 
    } 
    ] 
}
```

I want to show it on the html table using Datatable
Here is the html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Site Name</th>
                <th>Cabinet</th>
                <th>Count</th>
               
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

And the Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "user.json",
            "columns": [
                { "siteList": "siteName" },
                { "siteList": "deviceList:deviceName" },
                { "siteList": "deviceList:count" },
               
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

Please help me to do it any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user.json should looks diferent..

take a look here:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Comment: wait You need to create nested in table table ?